# How to pass dependency to test class in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    public HomeControllerTests(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {

    }
}
```

In the above class to test HomeController, I want to get StringLocalizer thorugh DI, which is used to create instance of HomeController. How to get it through DI?

Comment: normally you don't use DI in test method. Do you need it? why? Please also specify what unit test framework you're using.

Comment: you should avoid DI in unit tests, as that would mean you are now testing both the unit and the DI container.

Comment: @ps2goat: And the `StrongLocalizer` ;) Vikram, you have to use mocks instead of concrete classes for unit tests. Otherwise it becomes an integration test, which is something completely different

Comment: Also its best not to have to test controllers too and if you do, reduce it to minimum or use TestServer to do so. In order to achieve this you must have as less code as possible in your controllers and actions, no business logic

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You should read up a bit on unit testing and mocking. When you are going to test a class (such as a controller), you should only test the code in that class. If that class uses any other classes, ideally you would inject mocks into that class for those interfaces, and then test whether your class interacts with the interface as expected, but not test any actual logic outside of your class. You can do integration tests and end-to-end tests, later, but beginning with strict unit testing will help your code get better and avoid that ball of mud fast.

Comment: I am using moq framework. I am aware that when we unit test a controller, we have to mock all the dependencies. In this case, it did not make sense to me to mock StringLocalizer. Because, I have to test whether my method returns proper error messages which comes from resx files. If I mock StringLocalizer, i would be mocking messages also, and then I have to assert mocked messages, which did not make sense to me.